# Same datetime format for both display and input for DateTimeInput in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, python-datetime

By default Django displays date/time as something like `May 13th, 2010, 4:01 p.m.`. I have also configured a jQuery [calendar plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) (I used `dateFormat: "MM d, yy", timeFormat: "h:mm tt"` and I modified the JavaScript source code to output `a.m.` and `p.m.` instead of `AM` and `PM`) to display the date/time in the same format.

But the form validation (by default) takes in the form of

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
    '%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'
)
```

I tried to add `'%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p'`, but I'm not sure if `%p` accounts for `a.m.` and `p.m.` (notice the periods after the letters). Here is a link to Python's documentation on the [date/time formats](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

How do you guys do this? Do you just stick with Django's default (ugly) date/time format or do you somehow convert the time before checking for `form.is_valid()` (whether in JavaScript or Python)?

---

**EDIT** for @Thomas Orozco

I wrote a new form field called `CustomDateTimeField`:

```
class CustomDateTimeField(forms.DateTimeField):
    def strptime(self, value, format):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(value.replace("a.m.", "AM").replace("p.m.", "PM"), "%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p")
```

However my form uses `ModelForm` that has a dynamic `fields` under `class Meta`. Here is what I mean:

```
def order_edit(request, pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if foo:
        include_fields = (
            'fa_date',
            'sa_date',
        )
    else:
        include_fields = (
            'sa_date',
        )

    class OrderDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Order
            fields = include_fields

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderDetailForm(data=request.POST, instance=order)
```

where `Order.sa_date` and `Order.fa_date` are both `models.DateTimeField`. And I think I can only use `DateTimeInput` for `ModelForm`'s `widgets`. So how would I tell the form to use `CustomDateTimeField` for `OrderEditForm`? Do I need to add extra arguements via `__init__` and manually redefine the fields like `self.fields['fa_date'] = CustomDateTimeField(...)`?

Comment: I tried to modify `request.POST` by doing `.replace('a.m.', 'AM')`, but the `QueryDict` is immutable and Django didn't allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Initial answer

If you want your field to accept a particular format, the simpler solution would be to implement your own form field, which is usually pretty easy, especially here, given that Django handily provides you with an efficient base class.

Indeed, looking at the [django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py) for the `DateTimeField`, you can see that it inherits from `BaseTemporalField`. Therefore, you'll only need to subclass `BaseTemporalField` and implement the `strptime` method so that it accepts your input format.

Said input format should be passed to your instance through the `input_formats` variable, though this wouldn't be a requirement if you're willing to write a little bit more code.

You can also wade through the code for `DateTimeField` and `DateField` to get some inspiration.

### Edit

You actually [can override the fields of a `ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets): you just have to redefine them. In your situation, you however can't use a conditional block to do so (you can't have a `if` statement in a class definition!). So you have two solutions:

```
class SAOrderDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('sa_date',)
    sa_date = CustomDateTimeField()

class FASAOrderDetailForm(SAOrderDetailForm): #Inheritance matters!
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('sa_date','fa_date')
    fa_date = CustomDateTimeField()

if foo:
    FormClass = FASAOrderDetailForm
else:
    FormClass = SAOrderDetailForm
```

Alternatively, you could use dynamic creation of form classes , but that's sightly out of the scope of this question, so I'll leave you [with this post from James Bennett](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) that explains how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

What `%p` renders depends on the locale being used. I am not sure if any locale provides for `a.m.`/`p.m.`.

However, the easiest way is to provide your own validation function for your form field. If this is a one-off field, simply override the `clean_fieldname(self)` method of your form (where *fieldname* is the name of your datetime field). See [cleaning a specific field attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

If this field is something you will be re-using, create a custom field with your validation logic and import and use it whenever you need your custom validation. You can also customize the widget to render any jquery selectors as well.

Comment: I believe `clean_fieldname` will not come into play if your input does not pass field validation first, does it?

Comment: `clean_fieldname` is where the validation takes place.